Multiple imputation mice pmm
I need to impute 20 yes/no variables in my dataset. In this dataset, 35% of the individuals have all 20 of these variables missing, while the remaining 65% have complete data for these variables. Additionally, there are about 25 other variables that will be used as predictors for the imputation.
Since the group with missing data (35%) does not differ significantly from the group with complete data (65%), we do not expect substantial differences between the imputed and non-imputed data.
I used the MICE PMM method to impute the 20 yes/no variables, including the 25 other variables as predictors. However, the imputed data shows a much higher percentage of "yes" responses (sometimes 5 to 10 times higher) compared to the non-imputed data, which is unexpected. When I impute only one of the 20 variables at a time (ignoring the other 19) using the 25 predictors, the percentages of "yes" versus "no" in the imputed group are more as expected.
Example of one variable:
-45 times yes in non-imputed
-79 times yes in non-imputed + imputed if I only impute this yes/no variable
-260 times yes in non-imputed + imputed if I impute all 20 yes/no variables
Does anyone have insights into why imputing multiple yes/no variables simultaneously might result in an unusually high percentage of "yes" responses?

You seem to have a "monotone" missing data pattern, as defined in Section 4.1 of van Burn's Flexible Imputation of Missing Data (FIMD). Did you specify a corresponding "monotone" visitSequence to mice()? Also, was there a reason to replace the default logregmethod for imputing binary variables with pmm? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.
